# Linux doesn't detect Fn + F6 (toggle touchpad) combination on Lenovo V580 laptop

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, laptop, touchpad

Though there is "toggle touchpad" secondary function on F6 button of my laptop currently this shortcut doesn't work.

`xbindkeys -mk` command doesn't show any info when I press Fn + F6.

I couldn't find related option in BIOS (to disable/enable the function).

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
...
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
...

$ xev
...
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0xfa, subw 0x0, time 191258998, (90,247), root:(675,546),
    state 0x10, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5800001,
    root 0xfa, subw 0x0, time 191259362, (90,247), root:(675,546),
    state 0x10, keycode 151 (keysym 0x1008ff2b, XF86WakeUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
...
```

Linux Mint 17.3 x86_64 Cinnamon

Comment: `xbindkeys` is the wrong tool - try `xev` (and reposting isn't a good way to get answers).

Comment: @Thomas Dickey Updated the question with `xev` info.

Comment: @Thomas Dickey With regards to reposting. Is there a better way? Please let me know.